# Connection ended abnormally Spring Jdbc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm runnig a Spring Boot batch with two different connections. An Oracle DB and a DB2 DB both using `SimpleJDBCTemplate`.
The problem happens when I make a query for the second time about 1 hour after the first one happens because I have 300,000 inserts before runs the second time.

The Oracle connection keeps alive for so many time that I believe it throws the `IOException`.

I'm thinking about closing the Oracle connection before those 300,000 inserts...

Here is the stacktrace:

> Io exception: EDC8120I Connection ended abnormally.; nested exception
>   is java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: EDC8120I Connection ended
>   abnormally.
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)

Comment: Are you using Batch insert for Inserting rows?

Comment: Unfortunatly our server has a max 10000 inserts per time... I was using but the DBA told me to make one by one...

Answer (score 0):

Use batch insert by 1000 items in each iteration.

Comment: The problem was solved! I was using SingleConnectionDataSource that doesnt close the connection...after changing to commons dbcp BasicDataSource it worked fine!